# Issues Switching Users in Azure APIM Using Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management

I am working on a project that uses Azure API Management (APIM) and requires Azure B2C to authenticate into the APIM portal **and** to make API calls within APIM.  User accounts are considered "local" accounts in Azure AD (no social accounts).  As a developer, I have several Azure B2C user accounts setup so I can test different scenarios.

The problem I am having is that I haven't found a way to switch user accounts effectively w/o Azure B2C 'remembering' my previously logged in account.  Using MS Edge or Google Chrome, clearing cookies in the browser seems to have no impact on removing any previously cached login information.  B2C somehow still seems to 'remember' the user account I had previously logged in with.

To make things worse, I had deleted a user account that I had previously logged in with and after doing that, I couldn't login to Azure B2C at all and got an error in APIM stating that it couldn't find the account.

I've attempted to force a logout by calling a logout endpoint like this:

[https://*my_domain*.b2clogin.com/*my_domain*.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/**logout**?p=b2c_1A_signup_signin](https://my_domain.b2clogin.com/my_domain.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/**logout**?p=b2c_1A_signup_signin)

That seems to have some impact, but not always... and it didn't resolve the issue of the deleted account.

So in a nutshell, is there a way to switch user accounts using Azure B2C?

Answer (score 0):

As a very verbose way of doing it, you can try adding the parameter `&prompt=select_account` parameter to your login url.

Something like this:

[https://my_domain.b2clogin.com/my_domain.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=b2c_1A_signup_signin&clientId=..[many more]...&prompt=select_account](https://my_domain.b2clogin.com/my_domain.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=b2c_1A_signup_signin&clientId=..[many%20more]...&prompt=select_account)

Check your browser's navigation history if you have troubly finding out your login URL.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try incognito mode in Chrome? During auth process multiple endpoints are invoked, you could trace your auth with fiddler and notice endpoint that return set-cookie headers clearing cookies for these endpoints should result in "sign-out".